# Difference in means in multiple-choice poll

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, polling

Let's say that N randomly chosen persons where asked a question where the answer could be in either of X categories. For example, 500 persons where asked which of the top 5 political parties they support the most. Each person can give only one answer.

How do I determine if the leading party which, for example, got 33 % is truly larger than the 2nd largest party that got 29 % (on a certain confidence level).

Calculations like these solve my question when there are only two choices, but how about my case when there are several?
http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node85.html

Comment: you can find here a continuation of this discussion: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19537/simultaneous-confidence-interval-for-multiple-proportions-in-r/19597#19597

Comment: If the person can give only one answer then this is single choice, not multiple choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find out if there's any difference at all through [Pearson's Chi Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test). If this turns out significant, then do a (set of) post-hoc test(s), e.g. [Tukey's HSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test).

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use the "Simultaneous Score Intervals for Difference of Proportions" to solve your question. The reference is " Agresti et al. 2008. Simultaneous confidence interval for comparing binomial parameters. Biometrics 64, 1270-1275.

The corresponding R code is available in http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/cda/software.html

Sincerely,