# Which stat test to use for multiple-choice survey question analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

Let's say I have the following single-select survey question:

Which is your favorite drink?
(A) coffee (B) tea (C) soda (D) none of the above

And the responses are as follow:
(n=100) A: 80, B: 11, C: 9, D: 0

My question is which stat test(s) do I use to show that:

- % of respondents who chose A (top answer) is significantly greater than those who chose B (2nd most popular answer)
- % of respondents who chose B is not significantly greater than those who chose C

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you may have some pointers here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10544/difference-in-means-in-multiple-choice-poll

Comment: I ran a Chi-Square test, but not sure how to follow up with Tukey's HSD post hoc analysis in SPSS. Does Tukey's HSD work for nominal data?